# Behavior of setattr vs self.<attr> = value

Tags: python

Here's what I tried:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         setattr(self, "__hello", "world")
...
>>> A().__hello
'world'
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__hello = "world"
...
>>> A().__hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__hello'
>>>
>>> getattr(a, "__hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__hello'
>>>
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__hello = "world"
...         setattr(self, "__helloo", "world")
...
>>> a = A()
>>> vars(a)
{'_A__hello': 'world', '__helloo': 'world'}
```

Can someone explain the difference in behavior between using `setattr` and directly setting the value using `self.__hello`?

Comment: As you can see from the last line, directly assigning an attribute prefixed with a double underscore invokes name mangling.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you! "name mangling" was what I was looking for.